# Laravel Model query is slow, but fast on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table in my database with approx 400K rows, and I am executing the following statement (query that laravel is executing):

```
select * from `activities` where `device_id` = ? and `battery_level` is not null order by `created_at` desc limit 1
```

This takes less than 100ms when I execute it directly using a MySQL client. But laravel takes 1,5 - 2 seconds

My table looks like this: [image: table]

And how I use the models: (takes 1500ms)

```
Activity::query()
   ->where('device_id', 288)
   ->whereNotNull('battery_level')
   ->orderByDesc('created_at')
   ->first();
```

And with DB: (also takes 1500 ms)

```
 DB::table('activities')
            ->where('device_id', 288)
            ->whereNotNull('battery_level')
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->first();
```

I am looking to reduce this query to the same speed as MySQL between 100 and 200ms max. Removing the ordering desc reduces the time of the query, but I need to use order desc to get the latest.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If you run that code in `php artisan tinker`, does it still take 1.5~2 seconds? Are you sure you're not confusing application loading time with MySQL execution time? You can also use `DB::enableQueryLog()`, then execute your query, then `Log::info(DB::getQueryLog())` to show the query(ies) run and their timings, etc.

Comment: The speeds come from the query log, and yes same speed.

Comment: Figured that was the case, but had to ask  There is always going to be some overhead when running queries through Laravel's Eloquent or Builder engine, but that seems like a lot. I'll run some tests locally, see how speed compares in MySQL vs through Laravel. Maybe someone else will be able to help in the meantime; I'm not an expert on DB query speed optimization.

Comment: I don't see a `limit` used as the original query contains. Can you try adding a `->limit(1)` before the `->first()` to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Using first does that automatically. I checked the source code for this to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

It may be helpful to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Replacing `INDEX(device_id)` by

```
 INDEX(device_id, battery_leve, created_at)
```

*may* help.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$record = DB::raw("SELECT * FROM activities WHERE device_id = 1 AND battery_level IS NOT NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1")
```